# Global Lyapunov function. Definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Our definition of a global Lyapunov function for a system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ is the following:

Let a smooth scalar function $V\colon R^n\to R^1$ have the two following properties:

- $V(x)\to +\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert\to+ +\infty$ and
- for all $x$ which are not equilibria of the system (i.e. $f(x)\neq 0$) there exists an $m$ such that
  $$
  \frac{d^m}{dt^m}V(x) <0\text{ and }\frac{d^j}{dt^j}V(x)=0\text{ if }1\leq j <m.
  $$
  Then we call $V$ a global Lyapunov function of the system.

---

For example, we had that an Hamiltonian can be a global Lyapunov function if $H(x,y)\to +\infty$ as $\lVert y\rVert +\lVert x\rVert \to\infty$ and, except for the equilibria of the associated system, for each x there is some $m$  with the property above.

---

My questions are:

(1) Why $V(x,y)\to\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert +\lVert y\rVert\to +\infty$ and not as $\lVert (x,y)\rVert\to +\infty$? Or is this just the same?

(2) What if we have $V(x)\to -\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert\to +\infty$? Is this still okay?

For example consider the Hamiltonian $H(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}$. Then we have $H(x,y)\to -\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert +\lVert y\rVert\to +\infty$. So the first condition is not fulfilled. But the second condition is fulfilled. Nonetheless we said $H$ is a global Lyapunov function. So does it play no role whether $H(x,y)\to +\infty$ or $H(x,y)\to -\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert +\lVert y\rVert\to +\infty$?

Comment: The only thing that I don't understand: why do you want Lyapunov function for planar Hamiltonian system? What were you expecting to do with it?

Comment: We have a theorem that tells us - frankly speaking - in case we have a global Lyapunov function (as defined above) and that we have finite many equilibria that each bounded trajectory tends to an equilibrium in forward and backward time. We had some statements like that.

Comment: I'm completely confused because there are (IMHO) much clearer and "Hamiltonian" ways to check the last property. Also, you can never fulfill the second condition: $H(x(t), y(t))$ is constant along trajectory and it has **all** its derivatives equal to zero. What text do you use?

Answer (score 0):

To your first question: all norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, so $\|x\|+\|y\|\to \infty$ iff $\|(x,y)\|\to \infty$, because both are norms.

In your second question, the limit for your $H(x,y)$ is wrong, consider for instance setting $y=0$ and taking $x$ to $+\infty$, $-\infty$. There is no limit for that function as $x,y$ go to $\infty$.

Comment: @Rhjg Yes, I've edited it.

Comment: There is no limit for $\lVert x\rVert +\lVert y\rVert\to +\infty$? Why? Do we get $\infty-\infty$?

Comment: You get $+\infty$ in some directions and $-\infty$ in others. Namely, when $y=0$ you get $\infty$ as $x\to -\infty,$ $-\infty$ as $x\to \infty$. So, there is no limit.